# Is it okay to use the same reducer to update one of two state properties depending on other state value?

Tags: typescript, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-thunk

So let's say hypothetically, I have one reducer where I want to either update `state.propertyA` OR `state.propertyB` depending on the value of `state.propertyC`. something like:

```
const conditionalReducer: CaseReducer<StateType, PayloadActionType> = (state, action) => {
    if(state.propertyC === true) {
        state.propertyA = action.payload;
    } else {
        state.propertyB = action.payload;
    }
}
```

Is this considered good practice, or should I instead make two separate reducers and apply the conditional logic before deciding which action to run?

I have tried looking around for an answer on this but haven't found anything specific regarding this in particular. I am finding it a little hard to understand where to do what in the redux state flow and what is allowed, following best practice.

I am also using the thunk middleware elsewhere in the application, however I am pretty new to that but figured it could be worth to mention in case there is a better option including thunk!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is perfectly fine. If you take a look at the Redux Style guide, you will find that you should [put as much logic as possible into your Reducers](https://redux.js.org/style-guide/#put-as-much-logic-as-possible-in-reducers)

Comment: Ah, perfect thank you! this documentation was exactly what I was looking for. I looked into the redux site to look for answers, but didn't understand that the Style Guide section was about best practices!